# PHP not working on HTML file

Tags: php, html

This PHP code does not work inside an HTML file but it works if its a PHP file

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","aaaa");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("maptemp", $con);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$selectbox='<select name=\'userst\'>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
$selectbox.='<option value=\"' . $row['username'] . '\">' . $row['username'] .  '</option>';
}
$selectbox.='</select>';
mysql_free_result($rs);
echo $selectbox;
```

Comment: HTML files don't usually run PHP scripts. Use `.php`.

Comment: You must run a file with .php extension

Comment: You need to configure the webserver to interpret HTML files as PHP.

Comment: You mean if this code is in a file with the html extension?

Comment: @Bart Sure you *can*, but judging by the user's apparent knowledge I would say that may be bad starting advice.

Comment: @Wesley Murch I agree that is doesn't make much sense. But it's pretty much doable. We could also state that mixing HTML and PHP is bad advice.

Comment: Is it just me or has there been quite a number of topics involving running PHP from inside a HTML file today?

Answer (score 6):

Many (maybe most, all?) webservers aren't configured to look for `php` script inside `html` files out of the box.

Apache, a very popular webserver that [you might be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166607/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-apache-running-without-access-to-the-command-line), is an example of such a webserver.

You can, however, configure a webserver, like Apache, to do exactly what you want. If you can't access the Apache configuration files in the Apache directory itself (which is typical on shared servers, which, again, you most likely have), you can configure on a per-directory basis using [`.htaccess` files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html).

Doing this is pretty simple: open up your favorite text editor, throw this line in there:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

and save it as `.htaccess` in the same folder as your `.html` file. And that should do it.

I'd advise against this, though, as people (like webservers) don't expect there to be `php` script inside an `html` file. It's good practice to just stick to `.php` files for your `php` script.

Comment: By doing this when I refresh the page its download something without any extension.