# php will not run in my .htm page?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

[index.htm](http://mingamez.com/index.htm) I have 6 lines of PHP code that wont run on my page I don't get an error of any kind it just wont run if you look in source it shows my raw PHP. I have a file named [test.php](http://mingamez.com/test.php) that works fine. in test.php I only have those 6 lines of code that you can see in my index.htm

```
Server Name     defiro
cPanel Version  11.36.2 (build 9)
Theme   x3
Apache version  2.2.24
PHP version     5.2.17
MySQL version   5.5.30-30.2
Architecture    x86_64
Operating system    linux
```

i have tryed to fix the problem by putting `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in my websites .htaccess file as listed in [PHP not working on HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311817/php-not-working-on-html-file) i have tryed a few other things by trying to get an error out of the php with no luck

Edit__

it wont let me use php or html in a file together no matter if it is .html or .php it wont work i don't know how to fix it?

Comment: The server is looking at the file extension - PHP isn't invoked unless the extension is `.php` (and you tried to configure `.html` not `.htm`).

Comment: You say you want .htm pages to work with php but add a rule for .html?

Comment: i have used php and html in a html file before there shouldnt be a problem but there is i cant use html or php together in any file wether it is .php file or .htm / .html

Comment: "i cant use html or php together in any file wether it is .php" - Then how does this php page produce html? http://mingamez.com/test.php

Comment: add `rule` in htaccess

Comment: @MikeB cause it is making a request .. so why wont the request work on my main page?

Comment: "cause it is making a request" Makes no sense.. everything on the web is a request.

Comment: mike i know that. but im trying to figure out how to solve my problem i added the rule in .htaccess but still nothing

Comment: What rules are you talking about in .htaccess? It is difficult to understand your problem. You wrote: `"i cant use html or php together in any file wether it is .php` which is difficult to believe. If you add `<h1>TEST TEST</h1>` on top of your `test.php` file don't you get that in your browser?

Comment: @Mahendra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369781/htaccess-rule-to-parse-php-in-html-files-not-working i have tried these in my htaccess

Comment: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm this gives me a ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to see what error you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see

> index.htm I have 6 lines of PHP code that wont run on my page I don't get an error of any kind it just wont run if you look in source it shows my raw PHP. I have a file named test.php that works fine. in test.php I only have those 6 lines of code that you can see in my index.htm

Let me make some assumptions

- `index.htm` has php tags inside (`<?php echo 'if this works'; ?>`) that do not parse when you make your request. The tags don't even show up in your browser.
- `test.php` is a file that starts and ends with php tags (`<?php /*php content*/ ?>`). It runs as expected. (mind you, you can add content before or after php tags and it will be displayed **raw**).

If these assumptions are not correct please say so in a comment

Some other assumptions

- you set up your own server **or** you haven't fiddled with the configuration yet

### my suggestion

1. Go to your `httpd.conf` apache configuration file
2. Look for something that resembles the following

   ```
   AddType application/x-compress .Z
   AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
   ```
3. The one that's talking about php is the line you're interested in, it determines which file extensions will be parsed by the php interpreter **before** being sent to the client. OK, change it to look like this

   ```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
   ```
4. You can add as many space-separated extensions you want, but be warned, sometimes you want a raw file, so be carefull
5. **SAVE** and **RESTART** the server. Important, everytime you change the conf

Please give feedback if this does not help you

Comment: the other person helped me for a while it let my php work this helped me put php in my html files and run it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have put the following in

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

That targets .html files, You need to target .htm files so changing to

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

should fix it