# Why php tag is not working in html file?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a register.php file and I have defined $name="" inside that file

```
global $name;
$name = "";
```

and now in the html form I have:

```
    <form name="register" action="register.php" method="post" class="smart-green">


        <h1>Contact Form
            <span>Registration Form</span>
        </h1>
        <label>
            <span>Username:</span>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="username" value ="<?php echo $name;?>" placeholder="Enter your user name" maxlength="20" />
        </label>
   </form>
```

But the output is `<?php echo $name; ?>` instead of empty! Any idea of how I can fix this?

Comment: you cannot run `php` content inside a `.html` file your file will need to be `.php` to have it execute

Comment: @haxxxton That's not entirely true. Apache can be instructed to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah.. touché that is a good point. apologies for any confusion i may have caused

Comment: No problemo @haxxxton ;-)

Comment: He does mention that it's a .php file though, within the first 4 words :P Edit: Unless of course I'm reading that wrong, and the two files are separate?

Comment: He has 2 pages. One is register.php and the other is an HTML page containing a form.

Comment: duplicate of [PHP not working on HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311817/php-not-working-on-html-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your web server will server the HTML page as is. It will only parse the HTML as best as it can. If you rename your page with a PHP extension, the web server will parse it using the PHP interpreter and that is when PHP will be interpreted. Also as Fred points out in the comments you can tell Apache to treat HTML as PHP.

Comment: How can I say to Apache to treat HTML as PHP?

Comment: In the `httpd.conf` you would need to add a line similar to: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using apache2, you can specify a site specific
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/MySite.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
  <IfModule mime_module>
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php7 .phtml .html
  </IfModule>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Open your terminal window and make sure the module is enabled:

```
$  a2enmod mime
```

Reload the configuration:

```
$  systemctl reload apache2
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

rename the form file to '.php' in order for php tag to be interpreted.

In a php file you can have both php and html code, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

That right,
for the file to be recognized as php it's extension should be ex- form.php
that way it can be executed to give the output