# How do I redirect nonexistent pages to the 404 error page with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, bingbot

Apparently Bingbot is getting caught in an infinite loop on my site.  It downloads pages like http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/quicklist.html/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/applets/sounds/forms/linking/frames/document/linking/images/_AREA_onMouseOver.html .  Since I set my server to interpret .html as PHP the page is simply a copy of http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/quicklist.html .  **How do I stop Bingbot from looking for these bogus copies?**

**Why is Bingbot looking for those pages to begin with?**

I'd like to do something like the last line of the .htaccess file shown below (like at "[Redirect to Apache built-in 404 page with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447106/redirect-to-apache-built-in-404-page-with-mod-rewrite)"), but when I try `RewriteRule ^.*\.html\/.*$ - [R=404]` the entire site shows a 500 error.

Even when I use the last line below it redirects to http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/home/htmlcode/public_html/help.html which is not what I wanted.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html

RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^help\/.* help.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteRule ^.*\.html\/.*$ help.html [R=301]
```

P.S.  I know the site is way out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)/.+$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks that works.  I'd like to serve a 404 code though, but R=404 causes a 500 error throughout the site. Any idea why that may be? Also, why is Bingbot looking for those pages to begin with?

Comment: Have you verified that this works?  Apache docs state that it does not.

Comment: Of course I have tested it thoroughly before posting here. I like to know which Apache document says it doesn't work.

Comment: @zylstra: Another thing you need to keep in mind with `R=404` you will not see changed URL in your browser since Apache just does the internal rewrite. But if you run that in FIrebug you will proper 404 status coming back.

Comment: For Apache 2.2 the doc is here, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r , "...if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely..."

For 2.0 the doc is here, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags , "If you want to use other response codes in the range 300-400, simply specify the appropriate number..."

Comment: Yes I have already read that sections and made my comment accordingly. See my previous comments about status code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you either have `Multiviews` turned on, or apache is interpreting requests like `/quicklist.html/blah/blah` as a PATH_INFO style request, which will be interpreted as a valid request.

So turn off multiviews by changing your options line to:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
```

Then replace your last rule with:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: The `R=404` causes a 500 error throughout the site.  Any idea why that may be?  Also, why is Bingbot looking for those pages to begin with?

Comment: @zylstra what version of apache is your server? `R=404` works fine for me. No idea why bingbot is trying to request URLs with chained paths

Comment: `Server built:   Feb 28 2012 21:55:00
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.9.2 rev9999`
I guess this is another question though.  If you say 404 should work I'll try to debug that part of it.

Comment: @zylstra that's the version of cpanel. There's [a number of ways to find the version of apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166607/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-apache-running-without-access-to-the-command-line) but honestly, I'm not sure which versions support `R=404` and which doesn't. Apache 2.2 definitely does

Comment: I must have not copied all three lines, only the last two. My Apache version is: Apache/2.0.64.

However, the official Apache reference documents for both 2.0 and 2.2 state that "if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used."  So are you stating that you can see the page with a 200 response without the rewrite, a 301 response with a R=301 rewrite, and a code 404 with a R=404?

Comment: @zylstra yes, with those rules in a blank htaccess file, and apache 2.2, [it works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rvNkB.png)